# How do I show a limit at some point exists using the delta-epsilon definition, if I do not know what it's value is?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

How do I show a limit at some point exists using the delta-epsilon definition, if I do not know what it's value is?

For example how should I work with $\lim\limits_{ (x,y) \to (0,0) } (e^{x^y} - 1)/y $?  Even if you are able to identify its value, how would you go about it if you couldn't?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Thanks a lot :D

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: I think, in such a case, you would need to have a value of the limit in mind. $\epsilon-\delta$ proofs often hinge on 'working backwards from your conclusion', i.e., backing out the value of $\delta$ needed to make the algebra work out. So, usually you would probably compute the limit by conventional means, and then prove it formally. At least, this is what is done in my experience.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to make the limit more clear.

Comment: I would pick some values of $x,y$ that are closer and closer to zero and see if it approaches some known number. If so, try to prove it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was exactly what I was looking for